# Nx-Angular Dependency Injection crashes app

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, nrwl-nx

I have an nx project that is currently running as expected.

I have generated a `layout` lib that will handle the general layout of the app. It is simple component

```typescript
export class LayoutComponent {
  public isExpanded = false;
  // constructor(private drawerFacade: DrawerFacade) {
  //
  // }

  public toggleMenu() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }

}
```

Now I am trying to refactor this to be controlled by `NgRx`

I am using a Facade to help with this so I try to inject it by uncommenting the constructor above

Below is the error I get in the console

```
layout.module.ts:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'LayoutComponent' before initialization
    at Module.LayoutComponent (layout.module.ts:21)
    at layout.module.ts:20
    at Module.8931 (layout.module.ts:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.3746 (header.component.html:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.9355 (layout.module.ts:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.2577 (main.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
LayoutComponent @ layout.module.ts:21
(anonymous) @ layout.module.ts:20
8931 @ layout.module.ts:21
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
3746 @ header.component.html:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
9355 @ layout.module.ts:21
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
2577 @ main.js:15
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
773 @ app.component.html:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
8347 @ environment.ts:16
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
__webpack_exec__ @ sidenav.component.html:7
(anonymous) @ sidenav.component.html:7
__webpack_require__.O @ chunk loaded:23
(anonymous) @ sidenav.component.html:7
webpackJsonpCallback @ jsonp chunk loading:34
(anonymous) @ main.js:2
index.js:548 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
```

The drawer facade is a simple service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { drawerToggle, getDrawerOpen } from "@lpg/layout";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrawerFacade {

  constructor(private store: Store) { }
}
```

The dependency injection seems to be failing, how can I resolve this?

Layout.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HeaderModule,
    SidenavModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromDrawer.DRAWER_FEATURE_KEY, fromDrawer.reducer),
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent],
  exports: [LayoutComponent],
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

Comment: please provide the code sample of your LayoutModule

Comment: @GérômeGrignon code added

Comment: It seems like you need LayoutModule to import into your bootstrap module.

Comment: @a45b I have already imported LayoutModule to the AppModule. If I comment out the constructor in the LayoutComponent, everything works fine

Comment: I would try to use Injector.get(DrawerFacade) in ngOnInit instead of constructor to see if it changes anything.

Comment: thanks @PetrAveryanov, it didnt work. I managed to get where the problem was. The issue was webstorm being helpful in the line `import { drawerToggle, getDrawerOpen } from "@lpg/layout"` that was auto imported; I changed this to the file location and it worked